# From where does Costco get data correlating license plate numbers and vehicle make and models?

Tags: data-request, government, transportation, licensing, cars

International warehouse shopping chain Costco includes functionality in their [tire department website](https://tires.costco.com/) to enter a vehicle's license plate number to automatically determine the vehicle's make and model.

What data sources are they using?  Are there any open data sources?

I suppose they could be using http://www.vehicleregistrationapi.com, but that service charges $0.18USD per lookup in bulk.  I somehow doubt Costco is paying a third-party company every time a potential customer performs a lookup on their website.